# javascript: avoding if else with javascript object when pattern matching is involved

Tags: javascript, if-statement, branch, javascript-objects

I am basically trying to avoid branching. I will explain my doubt with the code:

My code is like:

```
name = "any_random_name_generated_dynamically"

//If else conditions
// foo and bar are the part of the name not the complete name

if (name.match('foo_pattern')) {
"do_thing_1"
}
else if (name.match('bar_pattern')) {
"do_thing_2"
}
else {
"do_thing_3"
}
```

Is there anyway I can avoid this using javascript objects? Or there any other way to do where less branching is involved.

I tried googling it bu didn't find anything for this particular issue.

Comment: your question is too broad/generic to give you a more specific answer than the one you have in your snippet.

Comment: I want to know about generic idea only. I want to practice that style..not only for this particular case.

Comment: @Thomas 
 
I want to know about generic idea only. I want to practice that style..not only for this particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a resolve table:

```
var resolve=[
  ["Some pattern",function(){alert("wohoo");}],
  ...
  ["",function(){alert("default")}]
];
```

So now you can simply iterate through the table, and find the first pattern that matches, and execute its related function:

```
var name="somestring";
resolve.find(el=>name.match(el[0]))[1]();
```

Note that this will crash if no pattern is found, so take care to add a default one.

Alternatively you could use a switch (still ugly):

```
switch(true){
  case name.match("sth") :
    dosth();
  break;
  default:
   dodefault();
  break;
}
```

Comment: thanks! learned few things here. but I am having problem in decoding the last part when passing argument to => function, can you please explain how it is working. I just learned about the => operator.

Comment: @tolboy you could also write var pattern=resolve.find(function(el){ return name.match(el[0]);});pattern[1](); so it finds the first pattern where the pattern ( position 0) matches the string, and then executes its function (position 1)